# Scraping data in consistency

Tags: validation, web, extract, screen-scraping

## I am scraping data from a website; however, the scores do not match with the fixtures.

## Scrape match data for each team and store it in a list of DataFrames

consolidated = []
for team_link in team_links:
count = 0  # Counter for the number of games scraped for each team

```
headers = ['Home Team', 'Home Score', 'Away Team', 'Away Score', 'Competition', 'Date']
r = requests.get('%s&teamTabs=results' % team_link)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

h_scores = [int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em:first-child')]
a_scores = [int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em + em')]

team = [i.text for i in soup.select('.team')]
comps = [i.text for i in soup.select('.tournament a')]
dates = [i.text for i in soup.select('.dateTime .hide')]
h_teams = [i.text for i in soup.select('.homeTeam a')]
a_teams = [i.text for i in soup.select('.awayTeam a')]

# Reverse the order of the scraped data
h_scores = h_scores[::-1]
a_scores = a_scores[::-1]
team = team[::-1]
comps = comps[::-1]
dates = dates[::-1]
h_teams = h_teams[::-1]
a_teams = a_teams[::-1]

min_length = min(len(team), len(comps), len(dates), len(h_teams), len(a_teams))
for i in range(min_length):
    if count >= 5:
        break  # Stop scraping if 5 games have been collected for the team

    if any(comp in comps[i] for comp in competitions):
        # Get the date of the match
        match_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dates[i], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').date()

        # Check if the match has been played
        if match_date >= datetime.date.today():
            continue  # Skip this iteration if the match hasn't been played yet

        team_1 = h_teams[i]
        team_2 = a_teams[i]

        team_1_link = teams_dict[team_1]
        team_2_link = teams_dict[team_2]

        team_1_r = requests.get(team_1_link)
        team_1_soup = bs(team_1_r.content, 'html.parser')

        team_2_r = requests.get(team_2_link)
        team_2_soup = bs(team_2_r.content, 'html.parser')

        team_1_data = team_1_soup.find('div', {'id': 'results'}).find_all('tr')
        team_1_info = [team_1] + [i.text for i in team_1_data]

        team_2_data = team_2_soup.find('div', {'id': 'results'}).find_all('tr')
        team_2_info = [team_2] + [i.text for i in team_2_data]

        data = [team_1_info + team_2_info + [h_scores[i], a_scores[i], [comps[i]], dates[i]]]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
        consolidated.append(df)

        count += 1  # Increment the counter
```

## above is the code i use to scrape the data. However should I remove these lines of code

## match_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dates[i], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').date()

## Check if the match has been played

if match_date >= datetime.date.today():
continue  # Skip this iteration if the match hasn't been played yet

## then the code returns the correct results; however, the incorrect fixtures as it scrapes fixtures not yet played. Below is a result of print(data)

#[['Real Madrid', 'Man City', 1, 1, ['Champions League'], '2023-05-09 20:00']]

## I note that the scores in the second row are for the next team in the list, in this case Arsenal, however, it is presented as Man City's score.

## Should I remove the datetime lines, the results are correct but match data is incorrect, seen below

#[['Man City', 'Man Utd', 1, 1, ['English FA Cup'], '2023-06-03 15:00']]
#[['Brentford', 'Man City', 2, 1, ['Premier League'], '2023-05-28 16:30']]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.